# How can I have a Xaml view in UWP?

Tags: xaml, uwp

In my project I added an XAML View, which doesn't have class behind, now I want to use this view for example on the page or some other class, but I don't know how?

Comment: Please take the [tour], and read [ask].

Comment: If it's a user control then just add an element with a namespace qualifier (most likely "local" and the name of your control, like <local:myCustomControl />. But judging from the series of questions you posted at once I think a tutorial on XAML and UWP should be sought out first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a code-behind file if you like. Make sure:

1. The XAML page has a x:Class attribute set to the name
2. Add a CS file in the same folder with the name [viewname].xaml.cs (where viewname must be replace with the name of the view)
3. Make the class public and partial

Once you've done that, it has a type that you can use to navigate to.